# Question to apt sources.list

Tags: debian, apt

is this the right format:

```
http://mirror/debian/security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

or this:

```
http://mirror/debian/security squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
```

squeeze/updates VS squeeze-updates (slash vs hypen).

I have seen both and the new debian sequeeze 6.0.2.1 seems to have the hypen version? Is this the new format? (Maybe I am wrong, it seems the current debian also has both, so they seem to be something different, who can explain it what the difference is.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which is the right format depends on how the mirror you're connecting to is configured.  Both of those formats are *syntactically* correct.  It's a question of whether the mirror you're using uses **squeeze/updates** or **squeeze-updates** as the code name.  Either could be used.

Answer (score 0):

The format used on all Debian installations I admin for is `squeeze/updates`, check for your local installation with `man 5 sources.list`.